# RewriteCond for subdomain in Zend Frame htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

- This from Zend

Need add this second part to code for subdomains

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+\.)?somesite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?city=%1 [L]
```

Try different example, but not working.

how to combine these two codes?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What represents `rel.l` in your condition ? What do you want to have for your condition ?

Comment: how to combine these two codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?city=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: have some problem with this code. css js and images don't want open in subdomain

Comment: I edited my answer. This is now how i would have done it (because previous code was yours with added rule). What about it ?

Comment: it's not work, but i modify previous version. for now it's ok. thanks